# Apparent hyperref conflict with datatool and longtabu col vertical alignment?

Tags: hyperref, datatool, tabu

Only when I turn on `hyperref` do I get a weird vertical alignment problem in the first column of a `datatool`-driven `longtabu`.  Without `hyperref`, the rows of the first column are vertically aligned to the top just like the other columns.  With `hyperref` turned on, the first column rows are acting like they have a built-in line break and drop down one line within the wrapped column.
MWE -- compare `hyperref` commented to uncommented:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{actionitems.csv}
ID|Project|Opened|Due|Issue|From|Lead|Closed|Note
1|Area 51|2012/12/12|2012/12/21|Prepare for the ending of the world|A. Crackpot|So Crazy||12/12 Survived the trial day \DTLpar 12/22 Bored now -- go on to the next thing
2|Roswell|2012/12/12|2012/12/21|Prepare for alien abduction|Tinfoil Hat|I.M. Gullible||12/21 Where are they? \DTLpar 12/22 Left Behind!
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb{actionitems}{actionitems.csv}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

% Note difference in vertical alignment of ID column with package hyperref commented or not:
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tabulinesep=1mm
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{ X[1,r] X[2,l] X[2,l] X[2,l] X[5,l] X[3,l] X[5,l] }

    \caption*{Open Action Items}\\
    \toprule

    ID & Project & Opened & Due & Issue & Lead & Note\\ \hline
    \endhead

    \DTLforeach*{actionitems}
        {\id=ID,\project=Project,\opened=Opened,\due=Due,\issue=Issue,\lead=Lead,\note=Note}
        {\id & \project & \opened & \due & \issue & \lead & \note\\ \hline}

\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get `Runaway argument?
\@nil \let \@dtl@line =\@dtl@trmstr \ifx \@dtl@line \@longempty \@dtl@condition`

Comment: The MWE compiled fine on my system (Windoz 7 and MikTeX 2.9). I.e: with the same strange interference with hyperref.

Comment: @Sveinung ah thanks yes, I had DL2012 but datatool was updated recently, just did a tlmgr update and now I see the described behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour is typical of the behaviour when a `\special` or other *whatsit* node appears in vertical mode. The document `grfguide` discusses this in the context of colour specials but it is a general problem.

The solution is the same as for colour, avoid the problem by getting in to horizontal mode.

This seems to work OK

```
\begin{longtabu}{ >{\mbox{}}X[1,r] X[2,l] X[2,l] X[2,l] X[5,l] X[3,l] X[5,l] }
%                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: While I can't really confess to understand, the solution does work.  Thanks!

Comment: hyperref places an "anchor" where the label is set so that it can jump there from any reference, but the anchor is a node so in a `\parbox[t]` or similar table cell aligning on the top aligns on the invisible node _above_ the first row. By getting `\mbox` in first you start the row before the whatsit node so that is _inside_ the first line of text, so the first item in the parbox is again the first line of text so top alignment works.

Comment: Interestingly, in the real-life document which the MWE modeled, there are actually four very similar tables one right after the other, and inserting the \mbox in only the first one cured the other three as well.